# Tensors products

Tags: tensor-calculus

I know the tensor product of vectors is a higher rank tensor, but can every tensor be represented as a finite sum of tensor products of vectors?

Comment: In the title you write "outer products" but in the text you mention "direct product". Which are you asking about and what do you think either of those terms means?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I meant direct product. I understand direct product to be the same as the tensor product, where the direct product of two vectors (rank 1) gives a tensor of rank 2 for example.

Comment: Ok. To avoid confusion please edit the post replacing "direct product", which is not well defined, with "tensor product", which has a very well known definition.

Comment: Also, just FYI this is probably going to be closed as off-topic because it's a pure math question.

Comment: Perhaps I should have explained more. Im asking the question as a help for GR, as a way of understanding how co and contravariant indices relate to vectors. Thanks for your anwser.

Comment: @RedSky Often people *define* tensors to be finite sums of  the "simple tenosrs" which are the tensor products of two vectors. Assuming the reference you're using doesn't define them this way you have to tell us what definition it does use so that we can answer your question with that definition in mind.

Comment: @Oscar Cunningham Indeed this is what I was getting at in my not-very-well-phrased question. Can any second rank tensor be expressed as a tensor product and sum of vectors for example? I am clear that not all tensors can be expressed as a product only of vectors, and there needs to be a sum also. But Ive not been able to find any discussion of this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Let $V, V^*$ be a vector space and its dual, respectively. A tensor is, by definition, any multilinear map
$$
\tau\colon V\times V\times\ldots\times V\times V^*\ldots\times V^*\to \mathbb{F}
$$
with $\mathbb{F}$ being any numerical field, the cartesian products being expressed $r,s$ times respectively and the tensor $\tau$ being said to be of rank $(r,s)$.

Cartesian products of maps can generate higher order tensors as follows: let $\alpha\colon V\to\mathbb{F}$ and $\beta\colon V^*\to\mathbb{F}$ be a $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ tensor, respectively. The tensor product map $\alpha\otimes\beta$ can be defined as
$$
\alpha\otimes\beta\colon V\times V^*\to\mathbb{F}
$$
such that $(\alpha\otimes\beta)(x,y) = \alpha(x)\cdot_{\mathbb{F}}\beta(y)$ however you choose $x\in V, y\in V^*$, $\cdot_{\mathbb{F}}$ being the product in the target field $\mathbb{F}$. The above can be generalised at will.

P. S. Notice that $\gamma\colon V^*\to\mathbb{F}$ belongs to ${(V^*)}^*$ which is *isomorphic* to $V$, but still not the same thing. As such you do not take direct product of vectors, you take direct product of maps (the above of which being accidentally isomorphic to $V$).